# get/have something to eat

Tags: word-difference

> **get** something to eat
>   **have** something to eat
>
> **get** breakfast
>   **have** breakfast

What's the difference between *get* and *have*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a clear difference between *get* and *have*.

*Literally* "get" means *to obtain*, but it can also mean *reach* or *attain* to something. You can speak of "*getting somewhere*" meaning reaching a place or a goal.

So for example..

> Let's *get* a sandwich for lunch.

.. really proposes the act of *obtaining* a sandwich, not eating it. That could include making it yourself, or perhaps buying it from somewhere.

Whereas..

> Let's *have* a sandwich for lunch.

.. is a proposition of *eating* a sandwich.

---

However both words are used idiomatically in connection with food and I note that there is a difference between *American* and *British* English in this respect.

Americans quite often order in restaurants by asking:

> Can I *get*...

This was once unheard of in British English, although may be used a little nowadays due to influence from American English.

Native British English speakers are more likely to order by asking:

> Can I *have*...

---

You have given an additional example in comments:

> He didn't get a thing to eat.

All of my previous reasoning applies. "Get" here refers to *obtaining* food rather than eating it, but obviously if you don't *get* any food it follows that you wont get to eat any either.

Of course there are lots of ways a person may *get* food - they may make it themselves, buy it, or be given it. As all the previous examples were *propositions* of food they only really allowed for the options where you get the food yourself. Your additional example is past tense which opens up further possibilities. Without any further context it could still mean that "he" didn't "get" any food for himself, but it could also mean he wasn't *given any*.

In either case, the use of "*get*" implies that food was not available, or possibly (as in the case of the very specific example you provided a link to) that he was prevented from eating.

If it said..

> He didn't *eat* a thing.

This has a completely different meaning. It could mean he got some food, or some food was given to him, but he didn't eat any of it.

Comment: I found this sentence "He didn't get a thing to eat." in an American English TV show, I'm pretty sure this _get_ here implies neither DIY nor buying. The context is that the man had ordered some foods first when someone phoned him, then he had to leave the restaurant without eating anything. So the _get_ in this sentence should be considered as eat, am I right?

Comment: @preachers Not necessarily. All the reasoning applies to your new example but I have updated my answer to include this.

Comment: If you've got the time you could watch the episode [here](https://youtu.be/2qMcg69IsTI?t=3m32s). This is the context I mentioned, though it maybe a little long. The sentence in qustion is right [here](https://youtu.be/36KJjhvA_hE?t=1m46s).

Comment: According to the episode, all the ordered foods has been served and ready to eat, they all have been _obtained_ already.

Comment: @preachers I had to rewind a bit to understand the context. Yes, the food was *obtained* but then something happened that *prevented* "him" from eating - his babysitter cancelled and he had to leave abruptly. So it wasn't that he didn't eat, he *couldn't* eat. This is why "didn't get any" is appropriate because had she said "he didn't *have* any" it could have meant he *chose* not to eat.

Comment: Okay, I see your point, in this case _get_ means neither obtaining nor eating, so what exactly does _get_ mean? Is this a special situation of using _get_ to express about eating?

Comment: @preachers I have added this detail into the answer but *literally* "get" means *to obtain*, but it can also mean *reach* or *attain* to something. You could say that he never *got* to the stage where he could eat something, because a situation arose that prevented it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80653/discussion-between-astralbee-and-preachers).